# Where (what specific folder location) is the default XSLT for viewing XML in IE10 and in firefox?

Tags: firefox, xslt, internet-explorer-10

I know that in firefox I can see the default xslt if I type in chrome://global/content/xml/XMLPrettyPrint.xsl BUT where is it in my computer? The actual file?

Where is it for IE10?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Mozilla uses a `.jar` file to pack such components but uses the file suffix `.ja` so that you don't find the stuff so easily :). So the file `C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/omni.ja` is a jar package and in there you have the directory `/chrome/toolkit/content/global/xml/` with the file. Of course the path `C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/omni.ja` can be different depending on OS and your Firefox installation.